# php register script not adding to mysql database

Tags: php, html

Just wondering what I'm doing wrong here guys. This is my register screen, I'm using an older version of php as im following a tutorial. The script so far detects missing fields and existing usernames, however when I try to register new user it doesnt add to the mysql database ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> Exercise 3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $name = “Frank”;
        $age = “28”;

        var_dump($name);
        echo "<br>";

        print_r($name);
        echo "<br>";

        var_dump($age);
        echo "<br>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the output when you attempt to add a user?

Comment: try `echo mysql_error();` right after `echo("<br>Input data is fail");`

Comment: You really should not tell someone that a user name already exists. It just gives a potential attacker one of the two pieces of information needed to hijack a user account.  You should simply try the insert and let it fail if the username already exists (do this by making sure you have a unique index on username). This also saves you a query against the database.

Comment: i got it working, thank you. just a case of mislabelled database field. thank you for the echo mysql_error() suggestion. really helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of things you need to change:

- I am assuming that your connecting to your database twice i.e `config.php` and by using `mysql_connect`.
- Your website is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. So use `mysqli_real_escape_string` or some other functions to prevent from such attacks.
- In the below query:

Change this:

```
    $taken=("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username ='{$myusername}'");
```

Remove those brackets like this:

```
    $taken="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE username ='{$myusername}'";
```

- Start using `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is being deprecated.

Comment: its only a college project on a portable server, no security risks will be a threat. thank you